# React canvas context.fillRect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, jsx

I'd like to draw rect with React,
is there anything wrong in the following?

I don't figure out why this code doesn't draw a rect.

```js
class GameView{
    constructor(props) {
        this.canvas = React.createRef()
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;

        this.canvas_style = {
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.width = document.body.offsetWidth;
        this.height = document.body.offsetHeight;

        this.canvas_style = {
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        }

        this.context = this.canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas id="game-view" ref={this.canvas} width={this.width} height={this.height} />
        )
    }
}
class View extends GameView {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        super.componentDidMount();
        this.context.fillStyle =  "black";
        this.context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas id="game-view" ref={this.canvas} width={this.width} height={this.height} style={this.canvas_style} />
        )
    }
}
```

I tried docment.getElementById("game-view") but I got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GameView` needs to extend React.Component, so React can render it.

The height of the container (`body` in this case) needs to be greater than 0, so the `canvas` would have some height.

`View` doesn't need to render a different JSX:

```js
class GameView extends React.Component {
  canvas = React.createRef()
  width = document.body.offsetWidth;
  height = document.body.offsetHeight;  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context = this.canvas.current.getContext("2d");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas id="game-view" ref={this.canvas} width={this.width} height={this.height} />
    )
  }
}

class View extends GameView {
  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    this.context.fillStyle = "black";
    this.context.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <View />,
  root
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```